# How to hover over an image but change multiple images in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with 50 images in (10x5) all are faded, and when I hover over an image it brightens up to stand out. 
What I am struggling with is hovering over an image and having multiple images in the table stand out as well. (The related images I want to stand out are at random in the table).

The script I have so far is this;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('.imgOpa').each(function() {
                $(this).hover(
                    function() {
                        $(this).stop().animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, 800);
                    },
                   function() {
                       $(this).stop().animate({ opacity: 0.5 }, 800);
                   })
                });
        });
</script>
```

If I could get any advice that would be great, even if it was to tell me that its impossible!

Comment: Are the others truly "random" or are they related somehow to the current element being hovered over? Are they stored in some data structure that you can access when $(this) is being hovered over?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, change the `$(this)` within the hover function to a class ... then all the images with the same class will be animated

```
$('.imgOpa').each(function () {
    $(this).hover( function () {
        $('.class').stop().animate({opacity: 1.0}, 800);
    }, function () {
        $('.class').stop().animate({opacity: 0.5}, 800);
    })
});
```

Or to better animate the associated images use `data`

```
<img src="blah.jpg" class="imgOpa someclass" data-assoc="someclass"/>
<img src="blah.jpg" class="imgOpa someclass"/>
<img src="blah.jpg" class="imgOpa someotherclass"/>
```

then

```
$('.imgOpa').each(function () {
    $(this).hover( function () {
        $('.' + $(this).data('assoc')).stop().animate({opacity: 1.0}, 800);
    }, function () {
        $('.' + $(this).data('assoc')).stop().animate({opacity: 0.5}, 800);
    })
});
```

this will animate all of the images with the class `someclass` (ie the first and second images, but not the third) when the image is hovered ....

Answer (score 0):

you mean like this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('.imgOpa').each(function() {
            $(this).hover(
                function() {
                    $(this).stop();
                    $('.imgOpa').animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, 800);
                },
               function() {
                   $(this).stop();
                   $('.imgOpa').animate({ opacity: 0.5 }, 800);
               })
            });
    });
</script>
```